# Python datetime get only days from datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I am making a website and I want to compare the dates but then when I do that it gives me an extra `0:00:00` which I don't want this is my code:

```
% if (datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") - cur_date).days <= 0:
      <kbd style="background-color: #a52c2c;">{{datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date() - cur_date.date()}}</kbd>

% elif (datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") - cur_date).days <= 2:
      <kbd style="background-color: #cc781e;">{{datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date() - cur_date.date()}}</kbd>

% else:
      <kbd>{{datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date() - cur_date.date()}}</kbd>
% end
```

I know it is messy but it works and it returns this: `3 days, 0:00:00` but I don't want the extra minutes etc. I know this might already be asked but I haven't seen anything

Comment: What template language is this? It seems this logic would be better on the backend but try `{{(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date() - cur_date.date()).days}}`

Comment: consider strftime ?

Comment: @roganjosh I am using the python bottle framework which uses `.tpl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice example for date comparison.

```
import datetime


str_date = "2019-03-18"

print(datetime.datetime.today().date())

object_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
if datetime.datetime.today().date() >= object_date.date():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

print((object_date.date() - datetime.datetime.today().date()).days)
```

Comment: The last line is your answer.

Comment: This works for anyone seeing but you will need to add own "days" or "day left"

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import date

CurrentDay = date.today().day
print(CurrentDay)
```

CurrentDay is what you want. It just prints the day.